# How to get the height of VBox before setting it to the parent

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, vbox

I have a VBox with elements and one Line(javafx). I want the line's height to be same as that of the VBox. These elements are put inside a Hbox and I have many such Hbox's.

The problem is vbox.getHeight() returns me zero unless I  have put the whole thing inside the scene graph.

Any alternatives to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the height of the line to the `heightProperty` of the VBox.

Comment: you mean bind Line's height to height property of Vbox ?